# The health tag and health of humans

Tags: discussion, tags

The [allergies](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/allergies) is used for animals with allergies and human's with allergies to pets.

Can the [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) be used in the same way or should we have a separate tag?

Example questions:

[Can I get sick from my cats sharing my food or drink?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/881/can-i-get-sick-from-my-cats-sharing-my-food-or-drink)

https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/917/can-contact-with-cat-feces-be-harmful-for-pregnant-women

Comment: Erm or do we migrate the questions lol 

http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/can-contact-with-cat-feces-be-harmful-for-pregnant-women

Answer (score 2):

Another suggestion may be to edit the [health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health) to include human health with respect to pets..?

Comment: This is probably the least ambiguous option.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion may be a [human-health](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-health) tag..?